# Which is most correct: "untransparent", "un-transparent", "intransparent", "in-transparent", or something else?

Tags: word-usage

I want to say that something is not transparent.

Which is most correct: "untransparent", "un-transparent", "intransparent", "in-transparent", or something else?

Comment: I'd probably go with "non-transparent".

Comment: I agree with hotlicks, but why not say "opaque?"  That avoids possible incorrect spelling.

Comment: I agree -- of the choices, "not transparent" is probably the best.

Comment: Something can be non-transparent without being opaque. Stained glass, for instance, is _translucent_. Likewise, metaphorically, an argument might be non-transparent (not obvious) but not totally opaque (inscrutable).

Answer (score 4):

#### nontransparent

or

#### opaque

Both mean not transparent.

Comment: Something can be non-transparent without being opaque. Stained glass, for instance, is _translucent_. Likewise, metaphorically, an argument might be non-transparent (not obvious) but not totally opaque (inscrutable).

Answer (score 2):

Non-transparent.  Or you could use another word for non-transparent, such as "opaque" or possibly "murky," although if something is murky, there is implied some possibility of sight, though far from transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I learned there's: transparent; translucent; and opaque.  I learned those three are meant to cover everything.  So the word you are looking for is either "translucent" or "opaque" (depending on the phenomenon, one or the other will be the correct adjective.)  I am sorry, I don't remember what textbook I would have learned that from so I cannot quote a source.  I may have learned that in a science class.
The only reason I can imagine for using the word "nontransparent" is that you want to describe a group of objects, some of which are translucent, others opaque, but THAT distinction (translucent or opaque) isn't important to your purpose; in other words, out of three possible properties of an object, in your context it's only important that it's either one (transparent) or one-of-the-other-two ("non-transparent").

Comment: We don't know the context. Government, computer code, and poker players, among other things, can be transparent in a non-optics sense. It's not clear that *opaque* is the opposite of *transparent* for these contexts.